# Can't Delete Object from DataTable in JSF 2.0 with JPA

Tags: jpa, jsf-2

```
    package com.jee6.beans;

import com.jee6.entity.Employee;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.transaction.SystemException;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class EmployeeBean {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ServicePU")
private EntityManager em;
@Resource
private javax.transaction.UserTransaction utx;
private List<Employee> emplist=new ArrayList<Employee>();
//private Query sql="SELECT e FROM Employee e";
private Employee emp= new Employee();


public Employee getEmp() {
    return emp;
}

public void setEmp(Employee emp) {
    this.emp = emp;
}

public List<Employee> getEmplist() {
    return emplist=findAll();
}

public void setEmplist(List<Employee> emplist) {
    this.emplist = emplist;
}

public List<Employee> findAll(){
    emplist=(List<Employee>)em.createQuery("Select e From Employee e").getResultList();
    return emplist;
}
public EmployeeBean() {
}
public String saveEmployee(){
    persist(emp);
    return null;
}
public String deleteEmployee(Employee e){
   try{
       em.remove(e);
       emplist=findAll();
   } 
       catch (Exception ex)
    {
     Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exceptioncaught", ex);
    }
   return null;
 }
 public void persist(Object object) {
    try {
        utx.begin();
        em.persist(object);
        utx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

I want to delete data from DataTable in JSF above code only got no output. I am try to fix that code and get no output. 
Before that I got IllegalException in delete method at (em.remove(e);).
Is there anyone who can correct me and appreciate for that.

Answer (score 0):

As you're not using EJBs, you have to manually manage all the DB transactions. You need to call `begin()` and `commit()` yourself **everytime** when you perform a DB action on the entity by JPA `EntityManager`. You are not doing that in the `deleteEmployee()` method.

Much better would be to move all that JPA works into a `@Stateless` EJB and inject it in turn as `@EJB` in your managed bean class. This way you don't need to worry about transactions anymore. For a kickoff example, see also the "update" part of this answer: [JSF managed-bean EJB injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626291/jsf-managed-bean-ejb-injection/8627413#8627413).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your getters should not perform DB actions at all. Your `getEmplist()` is invoking the DB everytime the method is called. This is unnecessarily expensive. Rather do the job in the bean's `@PostConstruct` method. See also [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062).