# How to get dynamically rendered <h:inputText> value in back end in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am able to render dynamic  but don't know how to get those dynamically created values in back end.

**test.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
        Insert Your Desire Number : <h:inputText value="#{bean.number}">
        <f:ajax listener="#{bean.submitAjax}" execute="@form" render="@form" event="keyup" />
        </h:inputText>
        <br></br>
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" />
        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
            <h:column>
                <h:inputText value="#{item.value}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{item.submit}" />

    </h:form>
```

If I render 3 input boxes, and when I submit the button i get the last value only, Can someone guide me how can i

**Bean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="bean")
@SessionScoped
public class Bean {
private int number;
private List<Item> items;
private Item item;
//getter and setter are omitted
public void submitAjax(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
{
    items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        items.add(new Item());
    }
}
}
```

**Item.java**

```
private String value;
//getter and setter are omitted
public void submit() {
        System.out.println("Form Value : "+value);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `submit()` method is in the wrong place. You should put it on the managed bean, not on the entity.

Thus so,

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
```

with

```
public void submit() {
    for (Item item : items) {
        System.out.println(item.getValue());
    }
}
```

or more formally,

```
@EJB
private ItemService service;

public void submit() {
    service.save(items);
}
```

Comment: Thanx bro, it works now... but initially i was also doing same but it didn't work at that time.

Comment: It's just a `@Stateless` EJB. If you've never used/created EJBs before, head to those related answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13012973 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/8627413 (the update part)

Comment: Thank you for your kind help, everything ok, but I want to change SessionScoped to RequestScoped. After changing to RequestScoped I get null pointer exception when I click to submit button. Any help please ?

Comment: Use the view scope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope