# How to prevent hard coded dependencies in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

If I work with JSF (version 1.2. or 2.0), I can manage JavaBean classes, which hold the methods and which are called or used by the JSF pages.

I can work with the `faces-config.xml` or with `@ManagedBean` annotation. Every way of solution has the problem, that I must refer concrete classes. In that way I build a hard reference on a specific class.

Exists a way of solution in JSF, to refer interfaces or abstract classes in `faces-config.xml` or with `@ManagedBean` annotation, which are implemented by a javabean. I mean the following: I won't refer concrete classes, I will refer a way of abstraction to give my application a way of possibility, to change or to grow with a suitable degree of maintenance.

Comment: You can check this link: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/
http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example/

Comment: JSF Boss has answered you... you will not get more detailed then this great BalusC

Comment: First of all, take a look on BalusC anwser. Second, if you really want to change your controllers, what's the problem with using interfaces or abstract classes (don't like it) and choose the concrete implementation in the faces-config.xml? That's exactly the reason why some guys choose this approach instead of the @ManagedBean annotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see how that ever forms a problem. A JSF backing bean is as being a controller tied to a specific view anyway. Perhaps you're tight coupling JSF backing beans with business service and/or database interaction code? In that case, you should decouple business service and database interaction code from the JSF backing bean classes and refactor them into fullworthy and reusable business service facade classes following the service locator pattern, using a business service framework such as EJB or Spring.

This absolutely can't and shouldn't be solved at JSF side. You seem to have missed the whole point of JSF in that perspective. JSF is merely a MVC framework for form based web applications, not a business service framework.

#### See also:

- [JSF Service Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011392/jsf-service-layer)
- [JSF managed-bean EJB injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626291/jsf-managed-bean-ejb-injection/)
- [Creating master-detail pages for entities, how to link them and which bean scope to choose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459903/jsf-application-correct-use-of-session-scope)
- [When is it necessary or convenient to use Spring or EJB3 or all of them together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369356/when-is-it-necessary-or-convenient-to-use-springjsf2-or-ejb3jsf2-or-all-of-the)