# How to call managed bean inside of stateless EJB bean?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, ejb, ejb-3.1, managed-bean

I wanted to know, is there any option to call a managed bean inside of EJB bean. Imagine, we have the code:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyManagedBean implements Serializable {
  public String getUrl() {
      return "http://www.google.com";
  }
}

@Stateless
public class MyEJB {

  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{myManagedBean}")
  MyManagedBean myManagedBean;

  public void setMyManagedBean(MyManagedBean myManagedBean) {
      this.myManagedBean = myManagedBean;
  }

  public void call() {
      // NullPointerException here
      System.out.println(myManagedBean.getUrl());         
  }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB {
  @EJB
  MyManagedBean myManagedBean;
  ...
}
```

... but it returns different `MyManagedBean` instance.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626291/jsf-managed-bean-ejb-injection

Comment: @johny, That's not my case: that guy asks how to call EJB inside managed bean, but I need to call managed bean inside EJB

Comment: No, there is no way. The EJB container is not aware of the JSF context of the bean you want to inject. Knowing the concrete problem you are facing would help to find valid alternatives.

Comment: Why would you want to inject a jsf bean into stateless EJB or any EJB?

Comment: @perissf, have a managed bean where I store some data for current session (user login and credentials if it does matter) - that's "myManagedBean". "MyEJB" returns some data from database. What data return depends on user account type.

Comment: @johny, answered above

Comment: Why dont you inject EJB in Managedbean and pass the values?

Comment: @johny, because it stateless and cannot have any state (fields) in it, because lifecycle of it is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not right. With CDI managed beans instead of JSF managed beans it's possible, but it is just not right as in, bad design. The business service should not be aware about the front-end at all. It makes the business service unreusable on other front-ends than JSF.

You should do it the other way round. You should inject the EJB in the managed bean, not the other way round. The EJB should be kept entirely stateless. You should just directly pass the EJB the information it needs as method argument (and *never* assign it as instance variable of EJB afterwards).

E.g.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped // <-- Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/q/7031885?
public class MyManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private String url = "http://www.google.com";

    @EJB
    private MyEJB myEJB;

    public void submit() {
        myEJB.call(url);
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

}
```

and

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB {

    public void call(String url) {
        // No NullPointerException here.
        System.out.println(url);
    }

}
```

#### See also:

- [JSF Service Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011392/jsf-service-layer)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just wanted to clarify something in your reply: "This is not right" means also "This is not possible at all." ?

Comment: I clarified the answer and added a "See also" link which should be good food for read and thought.

Comment: OK, I see. As I don't use CDI, the question can be considered as closed. Thank you!

Comment: Even if you used CDI, **you should not do that**. All self respected Java EE developers in the world would bludgeon you.